# hadoop multiple kms configuration

Tags: hadoop

I try to configure hadoop with multiple kms. I configured kms client part like:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri</name>
<value>kms://http@test1;test2:16000/kms</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hadoop.security.key.provider.path</name>
<value>kms://http@test1;test2:16000/kms</value>
</property>
```

server part like

```
 <property>
 <name>hadoop.kms.key.provider.uri</name>
 <value>jceks://file@/usr/kms/kms.keystore</value>
 <description>URI of the backing KeyProvider for the KMS.</description>
 </property>
```

But it seems the key will not be stored on both of the kms server. For example, when I use command like :

```
hadoop key list
```

I will get different result which is not right. It should be the case that no matter when or on which server I run the command, it will give me all the keys that have been create.
How can I configure the kms server right to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11862

From the above link we can get some clue. It seems that KMS now is not well designed for failover. There must be one master KMS and there can be several back up KMS. If the master KMS goes down, all the data that are encrypted can't be decrypted. In the worst case, if the master KMS goes down and can't be recovered, we even don't have replication of the keystore. In this case we will lost data. The best situation is that when other back up KMS is down, all other KMS will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your keys are in sync or not. The output of the following command should produce the same results on kms servers.

```
md5sum /var/lib/kms-keytrustee/keytrustee/.keytrustee/secring.gpg
```

If the output is different then Cloudera documents suggested to take a backup of the directory and contact their customer support.

The following can synchronize the keys at key trustee key location but be aware that you might lose your keys and make your encrypted data unreadable. So apply caution.

```
rsync -zav /var/lib/kms-keytrustee/keytrustee/.keytrustee \
root@the_other_kms:/var/lib/kms-keytrustee/keytrustee/.keytrustee.
```